# Bump node has some problems on a bevel object

Tags: bevel, bump

I have applied a texture to an object, using the bump node and then I tried to apply the bevel modifier (I have applied the scale of the object to make smoother edges applying the bevel modifier). But the result is that the texture results fragmented as you can see in the next image.

[image]

The nodes involved in the process are the following:

[image]

I think the UV is ok, because before the bevel modifier everything is ok, as you can see:

[image]

Can someone explain me what is going on and tell me how to fix it?

Comment: Please show your node setup. You can create a screenshot of it via Blender's Window > Save Screenshot (Editor) menu and then clicking on the node window. Also, did you UV unwrap your object after applying the scale and the modifier?  You can also share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page then edit your question here and paste the link into it.

Answer (score 2):

Bevel node has to make new faces with new UV coordinates.  The faces it is creating are long skinny trapezoids, that triangulate into unevenly sized triangles; mapped, with distortion, onto rectangles implied by the UV of your other faces.   You can minimize the issue by cutting that face up so that the faces the bevel creates are more evenly sized, and so that the most important faces it creates are not trapezoids at all but rectangles-- so, no UV distortion.

At least, that's my suspicion, without having access to your topology or UV.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't seems to work, I think there aren't issues with the UV, because before applying the bevel modifier, all is ok